# Using ++ operator in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import styles sheet:
import "./css/CommentBlock.css";

// import profile avatars:
import gamer from "./icons/gamer.png";
import man1 from "./icons/man (1).png";
import man from "./icons/man.png";
import user from "./icons/user.png";
import woman1 from "./icons/woman (1).png";
import woman from "./icons/woman.png";

let icons = [gamer, man1, man, user, woman1, woman];
let index = 0;

function CommentBlock(props) {
  // JS object destructuring:
  let { name, comment } = props;
  index ++;
  console.log(index);

  return (
    <li className="comment-block">
      <div className="avatar">
        <img src={icons[index % icons.length]} alt={name} />
      </div>
      <div className="comment-info">
        <h4 className="user-name">{name}</h4>
        <p className="comment-context">{comment}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}

export default CommentBlock;
```

**index value: 1 3 5 7 9 11 ...**

I'm really confused about ++ operator in react component.
I have 7 comment block but when I use index ++ in my component. I expect that index increases just one time. but index value increased for two times.

**I want to know how solve this problem ?**

Comment: I see `index += 1;` which is the same as  `index++;`. Where in the code you posted do you have a `++`?

Comment: I guess your question is not about `++` (which I don't even see in your code; I really feel that I've wasted too much of my time parsing your screenshot!), but about the rendering cycle of React or how components should manage state. As you've discovered, a globale variable updated during the rendering is not a solution.

Comment: Both index += 1 and index++ same work. and create 1 3 5 7 9 .. outputs

Comment: @mplungjan I just want to know why index increases for two times instead of one time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is about react render (the lifecycle of react),
and the fact that in development mode, react uses Strict Mode, which causes a double render of your component, moreover, you are using a variable to hold your data, any render of your component cause the index increase, I think for your case you show use the react's state.

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method Function
> component bodies State updater functions (the first argument to
> setState) Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer Note:
>
> This only applies to development mode. Lifecycles will not be
> double-invoked in production mode.

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Taken from react official docs
you can read about the strict mode and more explained about the state and the lifecycle of react.